# Google Appengine I dont want to redirect page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know this is simple but I couldn't succeed.
I add  data to database but I click the button my page is going to another page. Because I write redirect line. But if I don't write my process doesn't work. My codes are these:

main.py

```
class AddWord(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        word = Word()
        word.name = self.request.get("content")
        word.put()
        query_params = {'you added': word.name }

        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/add', AddWord),

], debug=True)
```

my index.html

```
 <body>

        <form action="/add?" method="post">
 <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Send Word"></div>
    </form>
```

When I write my word to textarea and click to button I don't want to go anywhere, but I couldn't handle form action parameter and the others. Please can you tell me what I must do? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't do a redirect, then when a user reloads the page, the form gets resubmitted.  This is undesirable in most situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the same rendering on your def get() into your def post() and apply the same variables to recreate the page with new messages.

Comment: so instead of self.redirect() i mean to just replace that with self.render with your index.html however you did it with MainPage if that's what you want to render instead of redirect /

Comment: but that doesnt make any sense. if I do that I write same code twice. This not good?

Comment: that's how webapp2 handler works, you can do multiple things to avoid duplicate code such as putting it in a function or creating a BaseRequestHandler for specific tasks and use same handlers.

Comment: np, another tip for your specific situation is create def process_data() which prepares/render stuff and just call it in your get() and post() then add your route to point to a single handler.